# What is the name and meaning of the second number at the end of a line in a Error Callstack?

Tags: javascript

I've thrown an Error and I know the one number is the line in the file but what is the second number?

somefile.js:43644:11
^file            ^line    ^?

Example Callstack:

```
Error:  Error: p1 was rejected
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/home/user/Node/async-demo/promise.js:6:16)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
```

I'm sure this is the easiest question but I don't know how to ask to search SO or Google.

Comment: Column (Xth character). If you google this exact question's title you would find your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it's [Class]:[Line Number]:[Character Position]